# mix: create new module in existing project

Tags: module, command, elixir, elixir-mix

Is there any handy mix command to add a new module to an existing elixir project?

I use elixir 1.10.3 and I have such project structure:

```
apps
--api
----mix.exs
----lib
----test
--inventory
----mix.exs
----lib
----test
--mix.exs
```

I would like to add a `monitoring` module.

Comment: That looks like an umbrella application. There's a mix command for creating a new app inside the umbrella (which is the same for creating an application ran within the apps directory), but to create a module why not just manually create the file? 

Comment: Like @sbacarob said there is no command to create new modules, just add a file in the correct folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no command to create new modules, just add a file in the correct folder.